# Find sequence of abc.. letters in string

Tags: c, string

Need to write a function that search inside a string a sequence of letters from the abc.. remove them and leave only the first and last two of the sequence.
For example if the input string is:
dabcemoqmnopqrrtaduvwxaz
the output should be:
da-cemoqm-rrtadu-xaz

this is the function I wrote:
but its not working...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("please enter a String");
    scanf ("%c", &str);

    for (int i=o; i< strlen(str); i++)
    {
        count=0;
        while(str[i+1]= str[i]+1)
        {
            if (count==0 || str[i+2]!=str[i]+1)
                str[i+1]="-";
            else
                str[i+1]="";
                count++;
        }

        printf("the correct String is:" %c, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that it is not working error do you get? Does it compile correctly?

Comment: `for (int i=o` is a typo? You put an 'o' instead of a zero

Comment: Also, the while loop appears to do an assignment (`=`) instead of an equality comparison (`==`). Thus you are changing `str[i+1]` to be one more than the value of (`str[i]+1`) every time you check the condition on the while loop.

Comment: `"%c"` reads a single char.

Comment: Note that using `strlen()` in the loop condition like that is bad practice in general — 999 times or more out of 1000 it is a performance bug.  It isn't likely to be critical for this, but it is good to avoiding bad habit when learning a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test runs:

```
Please enter a string: kswa0123456789abcdeffABCDEFQRSTUVWXYZaaaab
Input: kswa0123456789abcdeffABCDEFQRSTUVWXYZaaaab
Output: kswa0-9a-ffA-FQ-Zaaaab

Please enter a string: dabcemoqmnopqrrtaduvwxaz
Input: dabcemoqmnopqrrtaduvwxaz
Output: da-cemoqm-rrtadu-xaz
```

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];

    //strcpy(str, "dabcemoqmnopqrrtaduvwxaz");
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1)
        return(1);
    printf("Input: %s\n", str);

    int len = strlen(str);
    char *dst = str;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int k;
        for (k = i; k < len; k++)
        {
            //printf("cmp %d (%c) and %d (%c)\n", k, str[k], k+1, str[k+1]);
            if (str[k+1] != str[k]+1)
                break;
        }
        if (k >= i+2)
        {
            //printf("squish %d (%c) to %d (%c)\n", i, str[i], k, str[k]);
            dst[j++] = str[i];
            dst[j++] = '-';
            dst[j++] = str[k];
            i = k;
        }
        else
            dst[j++] = str[i];
    }
    dst[j] = '\0';

    printf("Output: %s\n", str);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the function does not do what you want. Either that, or I grossly misunderstood your intentions.

Also, you have a number of errors, or at least suspicious statements:

```
scanf ("%c", &str); // This reads a single character, not a string
int i=o             // Did you want a zero here?
str[i+1]="-";       // You probably meant '-', single quotes
str[i+1]= str[i]+1  // Eh? Did you mean `==`? Why?
```

I really don't understand how the code is supposed to work, I can't say how to fix it. I can, however, point you in another direction:

If I understood the requirement, the output string is possibly shorter than the input string. Working in-place (on top of the input) will only complicate things.

Try rewriting your algorithm to use an input string, and an output string. Copy over characters from a string to the other as they meet or do not meet the condition. Something that resembles this:

```
j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    if (condition(input, i))
        output[j++] = input[i]
```

"The condition" is vague, and I don't see it enforced in your snippet. You'll probably want to write a helper function, `is_abc` that will tell you if a substring is contained in the alphabet.

`tl;dr` you need to think this over. Possibly review your learning material.